# Access the values of variables after execution (java)

Tags: java, variables, jvm

How can the run-time assigned variable's values in a java program be accessed after the execution? 
Suppose I write a code to assign values to an array dynamically.How can the values of array be accessed by another java program after this program execution?

Comment: Are you talking about something like jconsole? You may be able to use jmx for that

Comment: Save the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the run-time assigned variable's values in a java program be accessed after the execution?

You can run multiple applications in one JVM.  You can all main on one program and later call main on another.  This way any data created by one program can be accessed by another.

Once a program exists, all it's state is lost.  Only data you saved to a file, or data store can be accessed by another program.